# Panel Header text in xhtml

Tags: jsf, primefaces, header, panel

I am trying to render a Panel header text based on some condition in BB. I am getting text value from properties files. But Is there any way we can get value of the header text from BB rather properties files?

Comment: I got the solution. Use facets.

Comment: BB = backingbean? Panelheader = a rocket? No code, no libraries, no version info. Please remove the question since it has no relevance in this format, or improve it like stated in [ask]